# How can I change the default location of a Room database?

Tags: android, android-room

I want to change the location of the Android Room Database. I know that the database is inside of the files system, and I need to get root permissions, but I do not want to root my phone.

The idea is change the database location to SD card, and can access it without root my phone

Comment: In addition to below-mentioned points, please make sure you have ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />``` permission in your manifest file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just put the location path in the name of the database.
I.e.:

```
AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
        AppDatabase.class, "database-name").build();
```

Put the router in database name.
I.e.:

```
 AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
        AppDatabase.class, "/storage/emulated/0/folder/database-name").build();
```

**and do not forget to give the write permissions to the application**

thx @vitidev

UPDATE

If you target Android 10 or higher, set the value of requestLegacyExternalStorage to true in your app's manifest file:

```
<manifest ... >
<!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting
   Android 10 or higher. -->
 <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
...
 </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: No it is not the proper solution..it will give u error as "unable to open database"

Comment: I did this and it's working good man, and if this doesn't work, please, put the correct answer.

Comment: i tried this code may times .. this not working ..i think it is not possible to change the path, ROOm designed in such a way..

Comment: @ArjunParth maybe you didn't request the permission to write to the external storage?

Comment: It does not work. The custom location database file is created and Room appears to save to it during execution. However, when I try to read the file back afterwards I just get an empty database.

Comment: @Tjaart it's working now for me in three different project https://imgur.com/a/vkXMPCA

Comment: it's work. if you do not forget about permission (+runtime permission for sdcard for MM+)

Comment: It doesn't work for me, even I added write external storage permission but it doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: I have also confirmed that this works, although I'm still a bit wary. You can see [here](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java;l=908;drc=d31ee388115d17c2fd337f2806b37390c7d29834) that `Context::getDatabasePath(name)` actually checks whether the first character in the name is a file separator character (`/`). So, as long as you specify an absolute path to the database file for the name parameter, this should work. I'm still a bit wary because this behavior is not documented and I'm not sure if it's guaranteed by CTS.

Comment: FYI, as an alternative, you can provide a `ContextWrapper` which overrides `Context::getDatabasePath(name)` and returns a database file that's not in the standard location. I've opted for this route because the behavior I mentioned above is undocumented and the CTS guarantees and API version compatibilities are unknown.

Comment: Turns out using a `ContextWrapper` and overriding `Context::getDatabasePath(name)` **does not work on older APIs** (starting somewhere around API 24). In [this commit](https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/frameworks/base/+/35871f2c2bb114806b4e3f109960b7f863d7885c:core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java;dlc=f6ede47b78f557d49a1e2273e37f355d39a75a59) (from 2016) `openOrCreateDatabase` was changed to use `getDatabasePath` rather than the private method `validateFilePath` which `getDatabasePath` previously delegated to.

Comment: In addition to above-mentioned points, please make sure you have ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />``` permission in your manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same. I was using same code as @joe06.

The only thing we are missing is that we need to create the directory before calling the Room build.

```
private fun setUpDirectory() {
        var dbDirectory =
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/data/abc/databases/"
        var dbDirFile = File(dbDirectory)
        if (!dbDirFile.exists()) {
            dbDirFile.mkdirs()
        }
    }
```

Building Room DB after creating directory will create the DB at any location you want.